# Autocomplete in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

i am planning to make an elastic search based auto complete module for an e commerce website.i am using edge_ngram for suggestions.I am trying out this configuration.

```
**My index creation :**

PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter","digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

**Inserting Data**

PUT my_index/doc/1
{
  "title": "iphone s" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/9
{
  "title": "iphone ka" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/11
{
  "title": "iphone ka t" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/15
{
  "title": "iphone 6" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/14
{
  "title": "iphone 6 16GB" 
}

PUT my_index/doc/3
{
  "title": "iphone k" 
}

POST my_index/_refresh

POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
  "text": "iphone 6"
}

POST my_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "pattern",
  "text": "iphone 6"
}

**Autocomplete suggestions**
When i am trying to find out closets match to iphone 6.It is not showing correct result.

GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "iphone 6", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}


**Above query yielding :**
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 7,
    "max_score": 0.28582606,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.28582606,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone s"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "9",
        "_score": 0.25811607,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone ka"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "14",
        "_score": 0.24257512,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone 6 16GB"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.19100356,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone k"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "15",
        "_score": 0.1862728,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone 6"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "11",
        "_score": 0.16358379,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone ka t"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.15861572,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone 5 s"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But result should be :

```
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "15",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "title": "iphone 6"
        }
      }
```

Please let me know if i am missing something on this,I am new to this so not aware of any other method that may yield better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `autocomplete_search` as your `search_analyzer`. If you look how your text is analyzed using search analyzer specified by you.

```
POST my_index/_analyze
{
 "analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
 "text": "iphone 6"
}
```

You will get

```
 {
 "tokens": [
  {
     "token": "iphone",           ===> Only one token
     "start_offset": 0,
     "end_offset": 6,
     "type": "word",
     "position": 0
     }
   ]
 }
```

Since all the documents have this (`iphone`) token in `reverse index`. So all the documents are returned

In case you want to match desired results, you can use the same analyzer used while indexing.

```
{
 "query": {
 "match": {
  "title": {
    "query": "iphone 6", 
    "operator": "and",
    "analyzer" : "autocomplete"
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please let us know how to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Thanks for the help.Furthermore i require to use phrase suggester over this.Can i do this ? i want to correct if user types ipone five and suggest iphone 5.

Comment: You will have to change your `analyzer`. Some analyzer that will index five as 5.

Comment: Lets say for now i don't consider this case(ipone five) .Let say user searched ipone 5 will this yield required result. I used this to search.

"suggest" : {
    "DidYouMean": {
    "text": "iphne 5",
      "phrase" : {
         "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
         "field" : "name",
         "highlight": {
           "pre_tag": "<em>",
           "post_tag": "</em>"
           }
      }
  }}

Comment: Getting weird output thats because of analyser autocomplete i think.

{
            "text": "i ip iph ipho iphone 5",
            "highlighted": "i ip iph <em>ipho iphone</em> 5",
            "score": 4.105417e-7
          },
          {
            "text": "i ip iph iphon iphone 5",
            "highlighted": "i ip iph <em>iphon iphone</em> 5",
            "score": 4.105417e-7
          },

Comment: Hi,Can you help me out on this as well? that will be a great help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973192/mappings-on-filed-elastic-search